# To find gradient of cost function using Wirtinger calculus

Tags: derivatives, optimization, normed-spaces

I want to get gradient of the following cost function.
$f(g,g^*) = \|(f-|Ag|)\|^2_2$
w.r.t $g$ using Wirtinger Calculus (i.e., derivating $f(g,g^*)$ w.r.t $g$ the $g^*$ is considered as constant and vice-versa).

where $\|.\|_{2}$ is the $L_2$ norm, $g$ is $n\times1$ vector and $g^*$ is its complex conjugate $f$ is real positive $m\times1$ vector and $A\in L(R^n,R^m)$ (Linear operator that maps a $n\times1$ vector to $m\times1$ vector) and adjoint of $A =A^{\dagger}$ defined such that  $\langle g_{01},Ag_{i2}\rangle=\langle A^\dagger g_{01}, g_{i2}\rangle$.

any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the meaning of the $|Ag|$ notation? Absolute value? Another norm?

Comment: Thank you @greg for the response. It denotes the absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\h{\tfrac{1}{2}}
\def\B{B^{-\o}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$For typing convenience, define the all-ones vector $\o$ and the variables
$$\eqalign{
h &= Ag &\qiq dh = A\,dg \\
b &= |h| \\
B &= \Diag b &\qiq B^{-1}b = \o,\;B\o=b \\
H &= \Diag h &\qiq H^T = H,\;\,B^T=B\\
c &= \B f \\
}$$
Note that $(g,h,H)$ are complex, while all other variables are real.

First calculate the differential $b$
$$\eqalign{
b\odot b &= h^*\odot h \;= h\odot h^* \\
2b\odot db &= h^*\odot dh + h\odot dh^* \\
db &= \h\LR{\B H^*A\,dg + \B HA\,dg^*} \\
}$$
Then calculate the differential and gradient of the proposed function

(which we'll denote as $\l$ to distinguish it from the $f$ vector)
$$\eqalign{
\l &= \|b-f\|^2_2 \\
 &= (b-f):(b-f) \\
d\l
 &= db:(b-f) \c{+} (b-f):db \\
 &= \c{2}(b-f):db \\
 &= 2(b-f):\h\LR{\B H^*A\,dg \c{+} \B HA\,dg^*} \\
 &= A^TH^*\B(b-f):dg \c{+} A^TH\B(b-f):dg^* \\
 &= A^TH^*(\o-c):dg \c{+} A^TH(\o-c):dg^* \\
\grad{\l}{g} &= A^TH^*(\o-c),\qquad \grad{\l}{g^*} = A^TH(\o-c) \\
}$$
When the cost function is real, a common short-cut in Wirtinger calculus is to treat $g^*$ as constant and omit all of the $dg^*$ terms. Afterwards, the gradient with respect to $g^*$ can be obtained via complex conjugation, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\l}{g^*} = \gradLR{\l}{g}^* \\
\\
}$$

---

In the steps above, a colon is used to denote the Frobenius product, which is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such a product to be rearranged in many different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you so much @greg for such a descriptive answer